# Asset Management, Zip Application with File previews?

Tags: macos, zip

I have large amounts of design asset files I have created and purchased (images, PSDs, icons, fonts, etc...)  These are really starting to take up a lot of space.

I would like to zip the files into an archive, but still have the ability to browse the files as I'm doing design work.

Are there an Mac zip utilities that would allow me to browse a zip file "in place" where I could see what the file content's look like without manually unzipping the file every time as this would be impractical?

Answer (score 1):

[BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com) is fairly comprehensive & has a preview mode, which can be toggled from prefs as to whether it will uncompress or open to preview by default. It also has a Quick Look plugin, which remains free even after the trial period.

[Zipster](https://coriolis-systems.com/Zipster/) tries to go one better by integrating zip files into the system so you browse them just like folders & can add/remove files without appearing to do anything other than drop/remove a file in a folder.

Overall, BetterZip is the more comprehensive tool… but Zipster is free, vs 20 bucks for BetterZip.

Comment: @Tesujin, Thanks for the suggestions. I've downloaded both to check them out.  I like the general way BetterZip functions, but it looks like it is unable to deal with nested zip files which is something I commonly am I working with.  So far I have been unabel to get Zipster to successfully install on Yosemite.

Answer (score -2):

i'm using winzip mac and double click doesn't mean unzip it